# Create a View which shows Nodes AND Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I am working with Search Autocomplete to create a suggestion list which includes nodes and taxonomy terms. Is there a way to include both entity types within a single view?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you want  to create a view to display all terms and all nodes

Comment: for starters yes, then an exposed filter by term: name and content: title

Comment: Is it for Drupal 8 or 7?

Comment: drupal 7, apologies

Comment: A view can only have one base table

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view and select show content of type All
2. Under format in show fields select fields.
   3.Create a relationship Content: Taxonomy terms on node
3. Select Content: Title and  Taxonomy term: Name fields under Fields
4. Under filter criteria select two fields first one Content: Title  and second one  Taxonomy term: Name and dont forget to check the Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it

Comment: Question didn't seem to imply that the taxonomy terms are related to the content.

Comment: correct, I'd rather not just have related taxonomy content.